# How to place centred and right-aligned <div>s beside each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to add some new text to the right of an existing centred heading.  It should all appear above the heading's (CSS) underline.  It's OK if the heading wraps onto a second line, but it should stay in the centre of the page.  In this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cL3s7kkz/), you'll see the main heading is shifted left-of-centre.  Worse, if you choose a short heading and 4-line side text, there's an overlap problem.

How do I get everything in the right place, as in this doctored image?

[image: how the div renders]

Here's my `div` before adding the new stuff.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h4>@Model.Heading</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Realistically, you can't.  All the different requirements are not hard to achieve in and of themselves, but when you add them all together, it becomes pretty close to impossible.  You want the text to exist on the right, but not push the text out of center alignment, but you do want it to push the text if the text will end up behind the overlaid text.  You want the overlaid text to be both out of flow and in flow, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap and column layout grids the best way I can think of is to right align your text I made a quick jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j0whk4zh/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 red">
        <h4 class="page-heading"> Variable Length Text which could take up the whole page!
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 blue">
        <div class="stuff">
            <p>add new stuff here</p>
            <p> and a bit more here</p>
            <p>add new stuff here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not really the layout I'm looking for.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty `<div>` floated left, mirroring the one on the right.  Use JavaScript to set its size, as in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL3s7kkz/1/).